# Android: duplicate entry in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to run my Android application with Android Studio, and it showed an error saying the following message.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/mikepenz/iconics/core/BuildConfig.class
```

It seems like there's a duplicate library, so that's why it stops running. But I honestly don't know which I should fix with the build.gradle file. So I put my build.gradle file here, and somebody please help me out.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//wrap with try and catch so the build is working even if the signing stuff is missing
try {
    apply from: '../../../signing.gradle'
} catch (ex) {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marshall.opensurvey"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def file = output.outputFile
                def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-v" + versionName + "-c" + versionCode + ".apk")
                output.outputFile = new File(file.parentFile, fileName)
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
            try {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            } catch (ex) {
            }
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            try {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            } catch (ex) {
            }
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories() {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'

    // Google Analytics Library
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

    // Glide Library
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    // Material Drawer Library by Mike Penz
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Android Iconics Library by Mike Penz
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:1.7.9@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:1.2.0.1@aar'

    // Circle image view library
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'

    // AboutLibraries by Mike Penz
    compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.2.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are conflicting.

`duplicate entry: com/mikepenz/iconics/core/BuildConfig.class`

This means two of your dependencies contain this class

```
// Android Iconics Library by Mike Penz
compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:1.7.9@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:1.2.0.1@aar'

// AboutLibraries by Mike Penz
compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.2.5@aar') {
    transitive = true // <- Why?
}
```

My guess is either the `transitive` shouldn't be specified or one of the `com.mikepenz` libs actually contains one of the other libs.  For instance if `iconics-core` is contained in `aboutlibraries` then you should exclude it by

```
compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.2.5@aar') {
    exclude module: 'com.mikepenz', name: 'iconics-core'
}
```

An easy way to track down dependency problems by running the gradle task `dependencies` via `gradle dependencies`.  This shows a nice chart of libs depend on other libs

Comment: the transitive is stated in the readme and will resolve all sub dependencies of the given library (which are recyclerview, cardview, appcompat in case for the aboutlibraries) android-iconics are no dependency of the aboutlibraries.